# JSLint unexpected 'that' message

Tags: javascript, jslint

I've just started using JSLint to make sure that the JavaScript code I'm creating at least meets some standards and I've got a confusing message:

```
JSLint: Unexpected 'that'.
```

The code is part of a solution to implement a progress bar, part of which is this object that handles timers and callbacks and is as follows (this is an extract from the beginning of a larger file, I can add the whole file if required):

```
var ProgressHandler = function () {
    "use strict";

    // Build a new object
    var that = {};

    // Add basic properties
    that.taskid = 0;
    that.timerid = 0; // Timer ID used to push refreshes
    that.progressUrl = ""; // URL to invoke to read progress
    that.interval = 500; // The interval for progress refresh
    that.taskProgressCallback = null; // The user-defined callback that refreshes the UI 
    that.taskCompletedCallback = null; // The user-defined callback that finalizes the call 

    // Set progress url
    that.setProgressUrl = function (url) {
        that.progressUrl = url;
        return this;
    }

    // Set frequency of refresh
    that.setInterval = function (interval) {
        that.interval = interval;
        return this;
    };
```

The message appears on the line that begins `that.setInterval`. There are further uses of that I but JSLint also says that it stops processing at this point. I've tried searching for this message but it's not listed specifically here or on jslinterrors.com.

Why is this appearing and what can I do to fix it? Or should it just be ignored?

Comment: When I run this through JSLint the error is thrown on `that.setInterval`.

Comment: Oops, looks like I should have said _third_ that. It is the that.setInterval line that I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you do not have a `;` after the definition of `that.setProgressUrl`. Changing to:

```
    // Set progress url
    that.setProgressUrl = function (url) {
        that.progressUrl = url;
        return this;
    };
```

Resolves the reported issue. You then have an issue in that you are missing a closing brace and semi colon at the end of the file, not sure if that is just a copy and paste issue. The complete script should look like:

```
var ProgressHandler = function () {
    "use strict";

    // Build a new object
    var that = {};

    // Add basic properties
    that.taskid = 0;
    that.timerid = 0; // Timer ID used to push refreshes
    that.progressUrl = ""; // URL to invoke to read progress
    that.interval = 500; // The interval for progress refresh
    that.taskProgressCallback = null; // The user-defined callback that refreshes the UI 
    that.taskCompletedCallback = null; // The user-defined callback that finalizes the call 

    // Set progress url
    that.setProgressUrl = function (url) {
        that.progressUrl = url;
        return this;
    };

    // Set frequency of refresh
    that.setInterval = function (interval) {
        that.interval = interval;
        return this;
    };
};
```

Comment: It's not a complete file, just the beginning of one which is why there are missing items.

Comment: @ClaraOnager, makes sense. Hope the rest of the answer resolves your issue

Comment: I take it that as a general principle for deciphering JSLint message that when you get an unexpected 'something' message you should look *backwards* from that point for potential issues.

Comment: @ClaraOnager. Yes - as far as I am aware JSLint works from the top down so the cause of any error should be on the line indicated or above.